# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have worked with CMD version of Elastic Beanstalk using eb on May 25.But today I am facing this issue while trying to hit the command 'eb init'.

I am attaching the screenshot here.Even though botocore module is present,I am getting error that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore'.

[image]

Am I missing something? Please let me know.

Comment: `where pip`. Most likely *Python* used is not the one you think it is.

Comment: Looks like `dashboard` is your virtualenv but `ebcli` installed in system python

Comment: (dashboard) C:\Users\Ananda.Roy\dashboard\Scripts>where pip
C:\Users\Ananda.Roy\dashboard\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Ananda.Roy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe This is the output for 'Where pip'

Comment: @rzlvmp - I did check which you mentioned but eb --version also throwing same error'No botocore...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling ebcli resolved the issue.

[image]

Thank you @rzlvmp and @CristiFati for your response.